# Angular Momentum -- AP Physics C

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws, universe, torque, solar-system

Do all of the planets in our solar system have the same angular momentum? If so, why?

I'm not sure if the following is correct: If we could drag a planet radially outward from the sun, then no torque would be exerted. So, if the universe formed this way or at least is this way currently, then angular momentum should be conserved since no external torques were exerted. Please verify or nullify this assertion.

Comment: Hint: the angular momentum is proportional to the mass. The fact that the planets have the masses that they have is not a deep dynamical property of planetary systems, it is a quirk of history.

Comment: what force would drag a planet radially outward from the sun?

Answer (score 0):

No. The angular momentum of different planets in our solar system varies by almost *five orders of magnitude*! See the data [here](http://www.zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/astronomy/Angular_Momentum.html).

The angular momentum depends on the mass of the planet, the radius of its orbit, and its orbital speed. For each planet, the latter two quantities are related by its equations of motion. But there is no suspected relationship between the masses of the various planets, and [hypotheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titius%E2%80%93Bode_law) of possible relationships between their radii or speeds are not well-established. So there is no reason to expect the angular momentum for each planet to be the same.

What *is* well-established is that the angular momentum of each planet is constant, or nearly so, because angular momentum is conserved under central forces, such as the Sun’s gravity.

Comment: Sir we read angular momentum changes when we change the point of reference is ,angular momentum of all the planets about sun is fixed ,about other planet is different.

Comment: You don’t want to take the angular momentum around a planet, because then the origin would be accelerating. You would be using a non-inertial reference frame. The Sun barely moves so it makes an almost-inertial origin. Even better is to take the angular momentum around the center of mass of the solar system.

Comment: So angular momentum of a planet about the sun and com of solar system is same

Comment: Almost. Not exactly. The Sun moves around the COM a little bit.